# Can I use conditional compilation to add missing types?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-compilation

The following:

```
#If False Then
    Public Type Long
        LoPart As Integer
        HiPart As Integer
    End Type
#End If
```

Throws a compiler error "Expected: Identifier" when run on my VBA7 32-bit office (Excel). This is because `Long` is a protected type. However, it was my understanding that the compiler should not see what's in the block (since the condition is always false).

Why do I still get the error?

I can still write and run code using Long variables - my type doesn't show up in intellisense. But the line

```
Public Type Long
```

remains red in the editor indicating some problem. Is it something to worry about?

---

NB, I'm trying to write a replacement for LongPtr for pre VBA7 systems where it didn't exist - in the off-chance that someone manages to run VBA6 in 64 bit office - I bet there's a way...

Comment: @RobertBaron No this isn't a duplicate, that question is about setting something based on a non-constant `#IF condition` - a condition that can't be evaluated at compile time because it relies on a function that doesn't exist yet. My question uses `False` at compile time which is valid (according to the [language reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/efd3d84d-0d78-4456-882e-8422cf2938a5)). I'm asking about the validity of what's inside the If block; namely a type that's illegal only under some versions of VBA/Excel

Comment: You tried to use `Const` and you got the same error?

Comment: @RobertBaron yep :/ - the 2 statements should be entirely equivalent anyway, since a `Boolean` is a form of *Numeric literal* which the language specification I linked expressly permits inside Conditional Compilation blocks

Comment: I guess then that the compiler compiles the contents of both the `#If` and the `#Else`. This is not truly conditional compilation as one would expect. I agree with you. It is a bit surprising!

Comment: @RobertBaron It's weirder than that; the automatic compiler used by the IDE flags it with an error when first typed and afterwards highlights it in red regardless of the condition. However re-compiling manually by running code or _Debug_ > _Compile_ will raise an error when the condition is True, but not when it's False (as expected). So only the syntax highlighting appears to be at fault - but I'd like a more thorough understanding in case I use this in real code.

Comment: If your application is a critical application, then you might want to maintain two versions of it to be on the safe side. Otherwise, keep it as is,

Comment: If ***WHAT*** is false in the first line of code? Is this a typo or is that your code? If it's your code, then that's the problem. If it's a typo, [edit] the question so that the problem can be correctly analysed.

Comment: @CindyMeister That is always False on purpose. The code in the compilation guard should not be compiled under any circumstances and that's what's confusing me; the IDE is highlighting it in red. In my real code I have a proper condition there, but this is just a min-repro. Note that as in my previous comment, this doesn't seem to lead to any issues unless I set it to True instead