# What really dictates pointer size in VBA?

Tags: vba, pointers, 32bit-64bit, portability

Conventional wisdom:

> In the latest version of VBA (VBA7),use the `LongPtr` type to
>   represent pointers, which works on both 32 and 64-bit systems. In old
>   versions of VBA, use `Long` to represent pointers (assuming a 32-bit
>   host, but [this is a safe assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827443/is-this-pointer-type-watertight#comment100220862_56827443) as all 64-bit hosts use the latest
>   version of VBA).

And what exactly is LongPtr? Well according to the [VBA language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type):

> `LongPtr` (`Long` integer on 32-bit systems, `LongLong` integer on 64-bit
>   systems)

Those two pieces of information confirm one fact: **On 32-bit systems, pointers take 4 bytes and should be stored in a `Long`, on 64-bit systems, pointers take 8 bytes and should be stored in a `LongLong`**

and by extension, `LongPtr` looks a bit like this under the hood:

```
#If Win64 Then
    typedef LongPtr As LongLong
#Else
    typedef LongPtr As Long
#End If
```

i.e. pointer size is linked directly to host bitness. In my experience this interpretation has always worked fine.

---

#### Problem

As pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56208872/6609896), pointers *tend* to be the same size as the bitness of the architecture. E.g. for a 32 bit program, pointers are 4 bytes, for a 64 bit program, pointers are 8 bytes. *However there is no reason for this necessarily to be the case*; a program with a 64-bit memory size may still use 32 bit pointers to navigate it.

That makes sense of you think about it. Just because my 64-bit program has used 8 byte chunks to split up its memory, doesn't mean I need 2^64 different possible pointers to navigate it. I may only have 16 bytes of memory in total, in which case my pointer could just be `1` or `0`!

---

So my questions:

- Are LongPtrs defined according to host bitness?
- If so, is there a reason that this is safe to do - is there something about VBA that means pointers will always match the size of the host program's bitness?
- If not, how are they defined?

  - Is it something to do with the compiler used for the host program?
  - Will pointer length vary between Excel or Word or SolidWorks hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two paragraphs before section 2.3

https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-VBAL/%5bMS-VBAL%5d.pdf

"An implementation-defined LongPtr type alias is also defined, mapping to the underlying declared type the implementation will use to hold pointer or handle values. 32-bit implementations SHOULD map LongPtr to Long, and 64-bit implementations SHOULD map LongPtr to LongLong, although implementations MAY map LongPtr to an implementation-defined pointer type. The LongPtr type alias is valid anywhere its underlying declared type is valid. "

Comment: I think I understand, but just to confirm - what is meant by "implementation" here? I assume it is implementation of the VBA language, in which case I think there is only 1 implementation (Microsoft's own - one for each bitness I guess) and so this recommendation essentially guarantees `Long` on 32 and `LongLong` on 64 bit systems, since that's what Excel does and by extension, what everyone must do. Is that correct? Or am I misinterpreting and this is talking about implementation of a host application, of which there are hundreds, so pointer size could vary app to app?